# Data Structure for implementing a registry of jobs, distributed to slave VM's

Tags: java, virtual-machine, distributed-computing, apache-httpclient-4.x, master-slave

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION:**

I have a distributed application based on Master/Slave pattern.
The master periodically receives a JSON file which is of following format

```
[{'key' : 'a_hashed_unique_key', 'partner_name' : 'name1'}]
```

I aggregate and write all the JSON objects with same ***'partner_name'*** to a file, this results in multiple JOB files (each corresponding to a partner_name).

All of these generated files are being written to  **Network Storage which is shared between Master and Slave**.

A Slave VM once powered on requests a JOB file and master shares the path of a JOB file on network storage and slave starts processing it.

**Question:**
What could be the best way to keep track of a job and the slave machine  that is processing the job file.

A hash based collection i.e HashMap looks appropriate, I would be accessing it concurrently and can think of following scenario's

- A slave requesting job file.
- Removing a completed job from the collection.
- Adding new job files as and when a new input file is received.

I would prefer an implementation with internal synchronization, so that the job registry can be read/modified atomically across threads.

Comment: so the master should update the shared file and the HashMap when it receives new jobs?
if i understood, you need something that permits you to have multiple slaves do cuncurrent writes and reads, but when master reads/write the structure it has to have exclusive access.
If it is the case it seems like the reader/writer lock problem.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the problem of concurrent reads and write to a file, So I have divided the input job file into multiple small files. Each of these files have jobs specific to a particular partner-name. I have NFS which is accessible to both master and slave. Master has the location of each of these partner specific input files and it just has to share the file location on network with a slave.
There is ONE-TO-ONE mapping between a file and a slave and I want to store this meta information at master for managing job requests.

Comment: yes but the HashMap you use to keep track of the jobs contains the information about every slave's job. "partner_name" seems a good candidate to be the map's key, i guess the map shoud have pairs like <partner_name, job id>, so the master can see each slave current job.
your problem is more about the cuncurrent access to the single job files or to the map that keeps track of the jobs?

Comment: I was also thinking on similar lines , and yes the problem would be during concurrent access.I have mentioned the concurrent access scenarios in the question.
Please note I am internally using the apache http core api and slaves use python urllib2 to request jobs from master.

Comment: so you want to use a synchronization mechanism between programs written in Java and Python..it is not easy and i think you should use some features of the underlying OS to do something like that. Have you thought about the slave sending a completition message to the master, and the master modifies the file? in this manner no synchronization is needed, except for master's threads.